How do I discover a Fire TV device with a custom player service using the service id?
I am probably missing something, but I cannot get device discovery to work for Fire TV devices with a custom player service. I initially was using the Fling SDK DeviceDiscovery API and couldn't get it to work. Now I am using Android MediaRouter to discover devices. I am following the documentation here:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fling/using-amazon-fling-with-android-mediarouter.html
I can successfully discover Chromecasts just fine. But finding my Fire TV device with a specific remote service ID doesn't work unless I use the default "amzn.thin.pl" service. This makes me think that my receiver app isn't configured correctly or something, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to work.
I tried running the "CustomPlayerSample" and "FlingSample" apps in the SDK, and they seemed to work, but the FlingSample app uses the "amzn.thin.pl" service. I replaced "amzn.thin.pl" with the SID of the custom player in the CustomPlayerSample app: "amzn.fling.sample.customplayer". No devices were found when I did this.
Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work? Is the Fling SDK broken? How can I discover devices that have my receiver app installed and then cast to that app? Is this possible without relying on the Fling SDK (maybe with the Google Cast SDK)? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the code for device discovery in the sender app:
override fun startDeviceDiscovery() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[startDeviceDiscovery]")

    _discoveryState.value = DiscoveryState.Discovering

    // The sid of the my custom player service. This does not work.
    mediaRouter.addProvider(FlingMediaRouteProvider(context, MY_PLAYER_SERVICE_ID))
    // The sid of the sample app player service. This does not work.
    //mediaRouter.addProvider(FlingMediaRouteProvider(context, "amzn.fling.sample.customplayer"))
    // The sid of the default player service. This will discover the Fire TV device.
    //mediaRouter.addProvider(FlingMediaRouteProvider(context, "amzn.thin.pl"))

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[startDeviceDiscovery] already discovered: ${mediaRouter.routes.filter { !it.isDefault }}")
    _devices.update { emptyList() }
    _devices.update { old -> old + mediaRouter.routes.filter { !it.isDefault }.map { it.toMyDevice(context) } }

    val mediaRouteSelector = MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO)
        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO)
        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
        .build()

    mediaRouter.addCallback(
        mediaRouteSelector,
        mediaRouteCallback,
        MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY or
        MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_FORCE_DISCOVERY or
        MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN or
        MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_UNFILTERED_EVENTS
    )
}

Here is the receiver app's custom player service code:
class MyPlayerService : MediaPlayerHostService() {
    companion object {
        const val LOG_TAG = "MyPlayerService"
        const val MY_PLAYER_SERVICE_ID = "com.my.player"
    }

    init {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[init]")
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        binder = Binder()
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        binder = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun createServiceImplementation(): CustomMediaPlayer {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[createServiceImplementation]")
        return MyPlayer(this)
    }

    override fun getPlayerId(): String = MY_PLAYER_SERVICE_ID.also {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[getPlayerId]")
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[onBind]")
        return binder
    }
}

The receiver app's whisperplay.xml:
<whisperplay>
    <services>
        <service>
            <sid>com.my.player</sid>
            <accessLevel>ALL</accessLevel>
            <startService>.player.MyPlayerService</startService>
        </service>
    </services>
</whisperplay>

The receiver app's AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_HDMI_SERVICE_ADVANCED"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAndroidTV">

        <uses-library android:name="com.amazon.whisperplay.contracts" />

        <service
            android:name=".player.MyPlayerService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <meta-data android:resource="@xml/whisperplay" android:name="whisperplay" />

        <activity
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|fontScale"
            android:name=".PlayerActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
            android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
            android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_your_company">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

